# orderedContent PyXB return empty lists

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyxb

I am trying to parse and XML file with simple and complex types using pyxb library. The following is the XML structure :

```
            </Requirement>
            <Section name="Electrical Characteristics">                     
            </Section>
        </Section>
    </Source>
</Requirements>
```

After reading writing it through pyxb I am getting the XML in following order where the order of Requirement and section is changed.

```
            <Section name="Electrical Characteristics">                     
            </Section>
```

```
            </Requirement>
        </Section>
    </Source>
</Requirements>
```

I have written a script which dumps XML to pyxb object and I used `orderedContent()` to preserve order in the following way.

```
ordered_instance = instance.orderedContent()
```

I am getting empty list in `ordered_instance` variable.